# Does Microbot Archive Apply to all Bases?

Tags: smash-up

The **Microbot Archive** minion states:

> Ongoing: After one of your Microbots (including this one) is destroyed, draw a card.

I assume, since it doesn't specify, that this applies to all Microbots on all bases, not just the current base it has been played on. Can someone please verify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes.** There's no rules reference for this one since it's just about the card, but as you correctly identified, it doesn't reference a particular base.